# Recipe App , best way to make selection for recipes?

Tags: java, libgdx

So I am designing a app with libgdx , kind of a simple app anyway. Its a recipe guide app.
What would be best way to render a selection screen for all the recipes , I was thinking create a table and display the recipes and make it clickable / touchable. However I don't know first way to start doing this in libgdx or if theirs a better alternative.

Ok I actually tried to make this work I am getting a error and i know what error means I am just having a difficult time finding what is null;

more eyes are better then one. err two.

this class is RecipeScreen

```
private TextureAtlas atlas;
private Sprite sprite;
private OrthographicCamera camera;
private AssetManager assets;
private SpriteBatch batch;

int[] blockMenu = new int[100];
public RecipeScreen(){

}
public void create(){

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(720,1280);

    assets = new AssetManager();

    if (Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.Android){
        assets.load("data/akemix.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
        assets.finishLoading();
    } else {
        assets.load("bin/data/bakemix.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
        assets.finishLoading();
    }




    if (Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.Android){
        atlas = assets.get("bin/data/bakemix.pack");
    } else {
        atlas = assets.get("bin/data/bakemix.pack");
    }



    sprite = new Sprite(atlas.findRegion("BLOCKBACKSEL"));


}
public void renderBlockMenu(){
    //batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    sprite.draw(batch);
    batch.end();

}



public void dispose(){
    assets.dispose();
    batch.dispose();

}
```

}

this class is start screen

```
public StartScreen(){

}
 SpriteBatch batch;
 Texture textBCKG;
 BitmapFont font;
 InputMultiplexer ui;
 boolean leftPressed = false;
 boolean screenTouched  = false;
 Debug debug = new Debug();
 RecipeScreen rScreen = new RecipeScreen();
 ScreenState sState = new ScreenState();

public void create(){
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    font = new BitmapFont();
    ui  = new InputMultiplexer();
    ui.addProcessor(new MyInputProcessor());
    sState.setScreenState(0); //set to start
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(ui);
    if (Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.Android){
        textBCKG = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/backgroundmix.png"));
    } else {
        textBCKG = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("bin/data/backgroundmix.png"));
    }
    if (Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.Android){
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("data/mixbig.fnt"),Gdx.files.internal("data/mixbig.png"),false);
    } else {
        font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("bin/data/mixbig.fnt"),Gdx.files.internal("bin/data/mixbig.png"),false);
    }


}
public void render(){
    batch.begin();
    if (sState.getScreenState() == 0){
    batch.draw(textBCKG,0,0,1280,720);
    font.setColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
    font.draw(batch, "                  BAKER MIX                     ", 180, 400);
    font.draw(batch, "                  Touch To Start!                  ", 180, 350);
    isStartHit();
    } else if (sState.getScreenState() == 1){
        batch.draw(textBCKG,0,0,32,32);
        rScreen.renderBlockMenu();
    }
    //debug.displayDebugCoords();
    batch.end();
}
public void dispose(){
    batch.dispose();
    textBCKG.dispose();
    debug.dispose();
    font.dispose();
}
public void isStartHit(){
    if (Gdx.app.getType() == ApplicationType.Android){
        if (screenTouched = Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            font.draw(batch, "BUTTON PRESSED!", 180, 300);
            sState.setScreenState(1);
        }
    } else {
        if  (leftPressed = Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){

            rScreen.create();
            rScreen.renderBlockMenu();

            sState.setScreenState(1);

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I seriously doubt that there's any one best way. Index by name. Index by one or more ingredients. Index by cooking technique, time, complexity, reliability, mess. Index by meal, by how much you (or friends/family) like it, by what it goes well with... and that's just a minute or two's thought.

Comment: I am bad at asking questions lol what im really trying to ask is how is there a good way to automatically generate menu like some apps have that you scroll etc.

Comment: Then, ask that question :)

Comment: like this is a example of what i want https://lh5.ggpht.com/QHysiFjAZ6n7MvlkDqLhx0KhvpiaeZluSwndsHPtPu3nPyEq5W402PulT1NTDi7qMRI=h900 how do you make a menu like that?

Comment: Well it all depends on your data base... Are your recipes already structured? Basically you would have to fetch a list/array of all "main" categories from your database and then draw each one as a block. But besides that: Why are you planning to do this using libgdx? Are you necessarily trying to develop for Android as well as  iOS? Or just one? Because for problems like this I'd generally recommend sticking to the Android SDK or iOS development stuff, which already provide awesome tools for creating those kinds of lists or views, which act much more immersive than when you reinvent the wheel.

Comment: "is there a good way to automatically generate menu" -- In general, no. If you don't want to design the interaction techniques, you're better off getting something like a database -- perhaps one already designed for dealing with recipes -- rather than writing your own.

Comment: So the android sdk has stuff built in for this for what im asking?

Comment: What's the error (I guess NullPointerException, from what you say), and what line triggers it?